# How to find some arrays with certain value and sum their values?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays with a lot of value. Where always the first and third element is repeated and I need to sum only the second element, because this is a number that I want totalizing.

Then make a new array with all values totalizing.

### Example

```
# My array

=> [ ['abc', 13, 40 ], [ 'abc', 20, 40 ], [ 'abc', 2, 40 ], [ 'cde', 90, 20 ], [ 'cde', 60, 20 ], [ 'fgh', 20, 50 ] ]

# My Expected Result

=> [ ['abc', 35, 40 ], ['cde', 150, 20], ['fgh', 20, 50] ]
```

What would be the optimal way to do that? What functions could be used to reach that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
arr = [[ 'abc', 13, 40 ], [ 'abc', 20, 40 ], [ 'abc',  2, 40 ],
       [ 'cde', 90, 20 ], [ 'cde', 60, 20 ], [ 'fgh', 20, 50 ] ]

arr.group_by { |a,_,c| [a,c] }
   .map { |(a,b),arr| [a,arr.reduce(0) { |t,(_,e,_)| t + e },b] }
  #=> [["abc",  35, 40],
  #    ["cde", 150, 20],
  #    ["fgh",  20, 50]]
```

This is how this works:

```
f = arr.group_by { |a,_,c| [a,c] }
  #=> {["abc", 40]=>[["abc", 13, 40], ["abc", 20, 40], ["abc", 2, 40]],
  #    ["cde", 20]=>[["cde", 90, 20], ["cde", 60, 20]],
  #    ["fgh", 50]=>[["fgh", 20, 50]]}
```

`map` passes the first key-value pair of the hash `f` into its block, assigning the block variables (using decomposition) as follows:

```
a,b = ["abc", 40]
arr = [["abc", 13, 40], ["abc", 20, 40], ["abc", 2, 40]]
```

and then computes:

```
[a,g,b]
#=> ["abc", g, 40]
```

where

```
g = arr.reduce(0) { |t,(_,e,_)| t + e }
  #=> 35
```

so

```
["abc", 40]=>[["abc", 13, 40], ["abc", 20, 40], ["abc", 2, 40]]
```

is mapped to:

```
["abc", 35, 40]
```

The two other elements of the hash `f` are computed similarly.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.group_by { |a,_,c| [a,c] }.values.map{|x|[x[0][0],x.map{|n|n[1]}.reduce(&:+),x[0][2]]}
```